# How do I match a data attribute with a select option and then display different content?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I have a dropdown with 4 options and I have 4 text blocks and 4 images.
Each of these have a matching data attribute. So for example, dropdown option 1 has the same data attribute as text block 1 and image 1.

The other images and paragraphs are hidden at the moment, but when I select the matching option from the dropdown they should display..

This worked when I was using li's instead of a dropdown with options.. I'm not sure what I need to do differently to fix this..

Any help appreciated.

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/yLJWLqB)

```
<div>
  <select class="tab-list-wrapper">
      <option class="tab-name" data-info="label1">Option 1</option>
      <option class="tab-name" data-info="label2">Option 2</option>
      <option class="tab-name" data-info="label3">Option 3</option>
      <option class="tab-name" data-info="label4">Option 4</option>
  </select>
  
  <ul class="tab-info-wrapper">
      <li data-info="label1">
          <p>Text Block 1</p>
      </li>
      <li data-info="label2">
          <p>Text Block 2</p>
       </li>
      <li data-info="label3">
         <p>Text Block 3</p>
      </li>
      <li data-info="label4">
        <p>Text Block 4</p>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <ul class="tab-image-wrapper">          
      <li data-info="label1">
          <div class="tab-image" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
      </li>
            <li data-info="label2">
          <div class="tab-image" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
      </li>
            <li data-info="label3">
          <div class="tab-image" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
      </li>
            <li data-info="label4">
          <div class="tab-image" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
      </li>
     <ul>
</div>
```

```
.tab-image {
  height: 30vw;
}

.tab-list-wrapper {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
}

.tab-info-wrapper {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
}

.tab-list-selected {
border-radius: 5px;
color: red !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 10px;
background-position: 90%;
transition: all 0.2s;
width: 60%;
}

.tab-info-wrapper li:first-child,
.tab-image-wrapper li:first-child {
display: block;
}

.tab-info-wrapper li,
.tab-image-wrapper li {
display: none;
}

.tab-image-wrapper {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
}
```

```
  $(".tab-list-wrapper option:first-child").addClass("tab-list-selected");
  $(".tab-list-wrapper option").each(function () {
    var _this = $(this);
    var this_info = _this.attr("data-info");

    _this.on("change", function () {

      $(".tab-list-wrapper option").removeClass("tab-list-selected");
      _this.addClass("tab-list-selected");
      $(".tab-info-wrapper li").hide();
      $(".tab-info-wrapper")
        .find('[data-info="' + this_info + '"]')
        .show();

      $(".tab-image-wrapper li").removeClass("tab-image-selected");
      _this.addClass("tab-image-selected");
      $(".tab-image-wrapper li").hide();
      $(".tab-image-wrapper")
        .find('[data-info="' + this_info + '"]')
        .show();
    });
  });
```

Comment: The change event occurs on `<select>` not on `<option>` as you have it coded

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? I thought I had it on option? Could you point out where is error is?

Comment: `_this.on("change"..`  won''t work because `_this` is an `<option>`. The event occurs on the parent `<select>`. Option elements don't have events in many browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to the `<select>` for the change event, not to the individual options.

Something like:

```js
$('select.tab-list-wrapper').on('change', function(){
    const info = $(this).find(':selected').data('info');
    
    $('.tab-info-wrapper li, .tab-image-wrapper li')
              .removeClass('tab-list-selected')
              .hide()
              .filter('[data-info="'+info+'"]')
              .show()
              .addClass('tab-list-selected')
    
})
```

```css
.tab-image {
  height: 30vw;
}

.tab-list-wrapper {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
}

.tab-info-wrapper {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
}

.tab-list-selected {
border-radius: 5px;
color: red !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 10px;
background-position: 90%;
transition: all 0.2s;
width: 60%;
}

.tab-info-wrapper li:first-child,
.tab-image-wrapper li:first-child {
display: block;
}

.tab-info-wrapper li,
.tab-image-wrapper li {
display: none;
}

.tab-image-wrapper {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select class="tab-list-wrapper">
      <option class="tab-name" data-info="label1">Option 1</option>
      <option class="tab-name" data-info="label2">Option 2</option>
      <option class="tab-name" data-info="label3">Option 3</option>
      <option class="tab-name" data-info="label4">Option 4</option>
  </select>
  
  <ul class="tab-info-wrapper">
      <li data-info="label1">
          <p>Text Block 1</p>
      </li>
      <li data-info="label2">
          <p>Text Block 2</p>
       </li>
      <li data-info="label3">
         <p>Text Block 3</p>
      </li>
      <li data-info="label4">
        <p>Text Block 4</p>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <ul class="tab-image-wrapper">          
      <li data-info="label1">
          <div class="tab-image" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?_=1'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
      </li>
            <li data-info="label2">
          <div class="tab-image" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?_=2'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
      </li>
            <li data-info="label3">
          <div class="tab-image" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?_=3'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
      </li>
            <li data-info="label4">
          <div class="tab-image" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?_=4'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
      </li>
     <ul>
</div>
```